# Использование кортежей для возврата error code, обоснованно?

Tags: c++, tuple

Мне одному кажется, что возврат error code с помощью кортежей не обоснован?

Намного лучше выбрасывать исключение и обрабатывать его выше

```
std::tuple<int, std::unique_ptr<sql>> execute(sql* db)
{
    auto result = sql::create_result();
    auto code = exec(db, result.get());
    return std::make_tuple(code, std::move(result));
}
```

Вообще, мне данный код не нравится

1) Почему мы возвращаем tuple, а не tie. Tuple копирует все объекты(конечно мы используем move, но зачем?)

2) Зачем мы используем кортежи? В моем понимании использовать кортежи надо только либо с вариадик темплейтами, либо если надо сравнивать большие массивы данных

3) Исключение в данном случае удобнее выкидывать эксепшном

4) Если мы используем вариадик шаблоны, то почему бы их не заюзать и не обрабатывать в дальнейшем результат пачками - в данном случае, мы не используем ни одного преимущества вариадик шаблонов

PS Собственно ваше мнение, я придираюсь или замечания действительно существенные?

Comment: @Abyx, ну мне кажется логичным при ошибках в ключевом процессинге базовых классов выкидывать эксепшн, не?

Comment: Почему мы возвращаем tuple, а не tie?  Потому что возвращается обьект, а tie это функция, которая  возвратит обьект. Так зачем возвращать то, что  возвратит результат? Проще срвзу вернуть результат. Хотя, в данном случаи, проще вернуть std::pair

Comment: *"Почему мы возвращаем tuple"* - кто это "мы"? Где вы взяли этот код? Может автор где-то поясняет, почему он делает именно так, а не иначе?

Comment: Tuple копирует обьекты, tie возвращает ссылки на объекты.

Comment: Написано очень много  классов по принципу "expected" который ответит на Ваш вопрос

Comment: Вот в этой статье можете увидеть почему исключения зло и какие ему предлагаются альтернативы https://habr.com/ru/post/430690/